# Does the limit exists in this topology on $L^0$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Consider space $L^0$ of equivalent classes of measurable real random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. Let $L_{+}^0=\{X\in L^0: X\geq 0\}$ and $L_{++}^0=\{X\in L^0: X>0\}$.

Consider the collection of balls $B(X,\epsilon):=\{Y\in  L^0 : |X-Y|<\varepsilon\}$ with $X\in L^0$ and $\epsilon \in L_{++}^0$. This collection is a basis generating a topology on $L^0$.

I am reading a paper with this set-up, and at some point the author defines the following:

$$Y:=\lim_{n\to \infty} 1_{A_n}X$$

for some $X\in L^0$ and some increasing sequence $(A_n)\subset \mathcal F$.

**Question:** Why does this limit exists?

The limit exists a.s. by monotonicity, but it seems to me that the topology they have defined is not equivalent to a.s. convergence.

Am I missing something?

Comment: almost sure convergence is typically not "generatable" by a topology. Just FYI.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes I found a post on MSE about that. But does this limit exists according to the topology they have defined?

Comment: What is the $|X-Y| $ used in the “balls” and same for $<$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $X,Y$ are formaly equivalent classes $[X],[Y]$. Define $|[X]|:=[|X|]$ and $[X]<[Y]\iff X<Y$ a.s.. Addition and scalar multiplication are defined as $[X]+[Y]:=[X+Y]$ and $a[X]:=[aX]$.

Comment: Do the$A_n$ cover $\Omega$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Not necessarily. They are increasing to $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, so that $1_{A_n}X \to 1_{\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n}X$ pointwise.

Comment: Are you reading [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002212360800520X)?

Comment: @RobertW. Yes! How did you know?

Comment: @Alphie Google search leads to this paper immediately. Anyway, it is not true that for each $\epsilon\in L_{++}^0$, eventually $|Y-1_{A_n}X|<\epsilon$ a.s. Thus, $1_{A_n}X$ does not converge to $Y$ in this topology.

Comment: @RobertW. Its equation (2.18) in the paper. Am I misunderstanding what they are saying?

Comment: @RobertW. Also it seems to me that if $[X_n]\to [X]$ in this topology then $X_n\to X$ a.s.. Is this correct?

Comment: @Alphie I think so. For a fixed $\epsilon>0$, $\sup_{m\ge n}|X_m-X|<\epsilon$ eventually a.s.

Comment: @RobertW. Actually I don't understand what they do in equation (2.18). Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your topology makes no mention of the measure $P$, so it certainly is not a.s. convergence, nor is it convergence in measure.

Among the positive functions $\varepsilon$ are the positive constants, so convergence in this topology implies uniform convergence.  Taking $(0,1)$ with Borel sets (and Lebesgue measure), consider $X = 1$ and $A_n=(\frac{1}{n},1)$.  Then $X_n := \mathbf1_{A_n}X$ does not converge uniformly, and thus does not converge in this topology.

---

What about "equivalence classes"?  In this example, we have
$P\big[|\mathbf1_{A_n}X - X| = 1 \big] > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, so taking $\varepsilon$ to be the constant $1/2$ we see that
$$
\mathbf1_{A_n}X \not\in B\big(X,\varepsilon\big)
$$
and $\mathbf1_{A_n}X$ does not converge to $X$.

We also claim that $\mathbf1_{A_n}X$ does not converge to any element $Y \in L^0$ not equal a.s. to $X$.  Indeed: If $P[X \ne Y] > 0$ there is (constant) $\varepsilon \in L^0_{++}$ with $P\big[|X-Y|>\varepsilon\big] > 0$ and thus $P\big[|X_n-Y|>\varepsilon\big] > 0$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: $|X-Y|$ is an equivalence class so it depends on $P$ no? I don't think its exactly uniform convergence, since $|X-Y|<\epsilon$ really means  $|X-Y|<\epsilon$ $P$-a.s.. Uniform convergence does not make sense for an equivalence class right?

Comment: @Alphie ... on this countable set $\{X_n : n \in \mathbb n\} \cup \{X\}$, uniform convergence does make sense.  But I added a note about equivalence classes.

Comment: Thank you. Am not sure what the authors mean. Its equation (2.18) in this paper. Do you think you can help me? https://www.mathematik.uni-konstanz.de/typo3temp/secure_downloads/91862/0/c3805bbe57a500404fa9fe60cafe8d6a51934d10/FKV_revised.pdf